# Configuração do arquivo Web.Config

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, envio-de-email, web.config

Gostaria de saber se consigo deixar o e-mail do destinatário no web.config, se der, como faço para implantar. Eu criei uma variavel e dei o valor do e-mail, porém se eu precisar alterar vou ter que compilar dnv, se eu conseguir colocar o destinatário no web.config e só pegar o valor de lá não será preciso compilar todas as vezes que o e-mail for alterado.
Obrigado

```
public void montarEmail(string nome, string email, string celular, string telefone, string assunto, string mensagem)
        {
            var servicoDeEmail = new ServicoDeEmail();

            var destinatario = "destinatario@qualquer.com.br";



            string corpoDoEmail = "Dados do contato: <br />" +
                                   "<br />" +
                                   "<b>Nome: </b>" + nome + "<br />" +
                                   "<b>Email: </b>" + email + "<br />" +
                                   "<b>Telefone: </b>" + telefone + "<br />" +
                                   "<b>Celular: </b>" + celular + "<br />" +
                                   "<br />" +
                                   "<b>Mensagem: </b>" + mensagem;

            servicoDeEmail.EnviarEmail(destinatario, assunto, corpoDoEmail);

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que você pode fazer é utilizar a classe **ConfigurationManager**, adicionando o destinatário no Web.Config da seguinte forma:

```
<configuration>
   ....
   <appSettings>
      <add key="myKey" value="myValue"/>
   </appSettings>
   ....
</configuration>
```

E acessar o valor da seguinte forma:

```
string userName = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myKey"]
```

Como mostra o seguinte link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4595288/reading-a-key-from-the-web-config-using-configurationmanager

Comment: Funcionou vlw!!!                                                                                
                                                                                                          
     var servicoDeEmail = new ServicoDeEmail();

            var destinatario = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailDestinatario"];
            var cc = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailCC"];´

Comment: @CarlosRoberto Que bom! Marca a resposta como correta pra ajudar outras pessoas que tenham a mesma dúvida.